# Mongo DB update query

Tags: mongodb

I have the below document stored in mongo DB collection,I will need to add new subscribers For eg.,I need to add the subscriber with "protocol" : "SOAP" and  url http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber3 for the name "name" : "FNOL","country" : "US","lob" : "property" from the document.

If the url we are adding already exist we shouldn't add to the document,in case if the document does not exist with matching criteria name "name" : "FNOL","country" : "US","lob" : "property" i would need to insert a new document.

is it possible to do all the above in a single command in mongo db?

Thanks in advance.

```
 {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b07fbbc0d7a677d2f8b2d87"),
            "name" : "FNOL",
            "country" : "US",
            "lob" : "property",
            "subscribers" : [
                    {
                            "protocol" : "REST",
                            "url" : "http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber1"
                    },
                    {
                            "protocol" : "SOAP",
                            "url" : "http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber2"
                    },
                    {
                            "protocol" : "JMS",
                            "url" : "NOTIFICATION.TOPIC.FNOL"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

After updation:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b07fbbc0d7a677d2f8b2d87"),
            "name" : "FNOL",
            "country" : "US",
            "lob" : "property",
            "subscribers" : [

                    {
                            "protocol" : "SOAP",
                            "url" : "http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber2"
                    },
                    {
                            "protocol" : "JMS",
                            "url" : "NOTIFICATION.TOPIC.FNOL"
                    },
                    {
                            "protocol" : "SOAP",
                            "url" : "http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber2"
                    }
        ,
                    {
                            "protocol" : "SOAP",
                            "url" : "http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber3"
                    }   
            ]
    }
```

Comment: Note that `$addToSet` will still actually add the entry if the `url` exists but the `protocol` is different. Therefore it's not actually be best option here. Use `$ne` to test for the presence of the value in the array instead for that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)... It will not push the data if it already exist in the array

```
db.collection.update(
  { name: 'FNOL', country: 'US', lob: 'property' },
  { $addToSet: { subscribers: { "protocol" : "SOAP", url: 'http://localhost.8080/FNOL/subscriber3' } } },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Comment: Hi Ashish,Thanks it works for the scenario when the subscriber does not exist and it exists as expected,but when there is no match  { name: 'FNOL', country: 'US', lob: 'property' } i would also need to add a new document.is it possible with single statement?

Comment: check the updated answer... upsert true will do this

Comment: worked like a charm.I have accepted the answer.By the way iam newbie to Mongo DB.Is there any quickway i can master mongo db??

Comment: yes indeed it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**db.collection.update( { "_id": (id of the object) }, { "$push": {"subscribers": { "url": "(input url )", "protocol": "(input protocol)" } } } )**